# Xamarin.Forms - need to get resulting HTML from a page execution (CGI on server)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and need to:

1. call an HTML page which is a CGI page executing on the server.
2. retrieve the resulting page's content.

What is the best method in C# to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string html = string.Empty;

using (var http = new HttpClient(()) {
  html = await http.GetStringAsync("http://www.url.com");
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I had tried this and it does work on other pages/sites, just not mine.  I figure there's something more to do on my CGI page.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: does your site rely on javascript to do any loading?  If so, a simple html scrape will not capture it.

Comment: No, there's no JS in this case.  However, I think I figured out something and still need a solution... my URL contains a CGI executable in addition to the target HTML page.  Running the link in the browser directly, all works fine and I can see the resulting (executed) text that I need.  When I put this into the GetStringAsync, it returns something resembling headers, but def not the resulting text.

Comment: So my call looks something like this:  https://example.com/cgi-bin/runme.exe/login.htm?pin=123   (I can take away the SSL and just use http for testing and this makes no difference, but ultimately I do need SSL calls)

Comment: without knowing more detail about what the server is doing I can't help much.  You could try loading the page in a webview and then getting the resulting DOM, or using a headless browser framework

Comment: Ok, I've no clue how to do either of those.  What is involved in getting webview resulting dom/text?  By the way the CGI program is just a server-side tech and returns html page.

Comment: I think if that was all the CGI was doing you wouldn't be having this problem.  Have you looked at it with the debug console of your browser?  Is it sending any strange status codes or redirects?